# Meaning of "invested in vetting" in a context

Tags: word-meaning

Here is a paragraph from an article on www.marketplacepulse.com. I cannot understant what the the expression in bold means. Does it mean that Walmart helped their suppliers in any ways or does it mean that they carried out regular inspections on the quality of their products? Or something else?

*Before online retail, supply chains relied on friction to achieve quality. Becoming a vendor to Walmart required years of work and experience. Those vendor relationships were precious and would last for decades. Because of how hard it was to build one, Walmart could trust on the network of vendors to keep up the quality. In turn, **they were invested in vetting** their suppliers. Friction in the system meant the supply chain could be trusted. And if anything went wrong, there was a clear path to follow to find the responsible party.*

Answer (score 1):

The piece contains some poor English. We do not say 'trust on'. To 'be invested in' is something can mean to have taken care over it and therefore to place a high importance on that thing. Walmart placed a high importance on vetting their suppliers. It is chiefly a US idiom.

> be deeply invested in (idiom)
>
> chiefly US
>
> to have given a lot of time and effort to something and care about it
>   very much

[Deeply invested in (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be%20deeply%20invested%20in)